# Dropdownlist in hovermenuextender

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I have dropdownlist in hovermenuextender, in Gridview. Below is the code.

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ASSIGN" ShowHeader="False">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Assign"></asp:LinkButton>

                                    <asp:Panel ID="popupMenu" Height="200px" Width="300px" runat="server" Style="display: none; background-color: #bddee0; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 10px">
                                        <div style="border: 1px outset white; padding: 2px;">
                                            <div>
                                                <asp:Label ID="call_no1" runat="server" Text="Label1"></asp:Label><br />
                                                <asp:Label ID="con_dept" runat="server" Text="Assign Call To : "></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />
                                                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Assign" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="assign" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                    <cc11:HoverMenuExtender ID="HoverMenuExtender1" runat="Server"
                                        TargetControlID="LinkButton1"
                                        PopupControlID="popupMenu"
                                        PopupPosition="Right"
                                        OffsetX="0"
                                        OffsetY="0"
                                        PopDelay="50" />

                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am binding the dropdownlist dynamically. If the dropdownlist has more items, listitems will be displayed out of the panel. And I select any of those, hovermenuextender hides.I want to have that extender shown after selecting any item in the dropdownlist.
Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Finally I replaced Dropdownlist with ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script

```
<script>
function ddlOnBlur() 
{


    var currentBehavior = null;
    var allBehaviors = Sys.Application.getComponents();
    for (var loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < allBehaviors.length; loopIndex++) 
        {
            currentBehavior = allBehaviors[loopIndex];
            if (currentBehavior.get_name() == "HoverMenuBehavior") 
               {
               // Now we get the ClientBehavior here: currentBehavior!
               currentBehavior._onHover();
               }
         }
}
</script>
```

**(Or)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ddlOnBlur() {
            $find("HME1")._onHover();
        }
</script>
```

**(OR)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showHoverMenu() {
            var hm = $find("HoverMenuExtender1");
            hm._popupBehavior.show();
            if ($common.getCurrentStyle(hm._popupElement, 'display') == 'none') {
                hm._popupElement.style.display = 'block';
            }
            hm._popupBehavior.set_x(hm._getLeftOffset());
            hm._popupBehavior.set_y(hm._getTopOffset());
        }
  </script>
```

For this Script you just make HoverMenuExtender id as HoverMenuExtender1 not use behaviorID

Please Refer :

http://forums.asp.net/p/1329061/2669385.aspx#2669385
http://forums.asp.net/p/1350055/2765769.aspx#2765769
http://forums.asp.net/p/1396306/3012651.aspx#3012651

Comment: Where do I call this function? And HoverMenuBehavior is the name of the extender?

Comment: Put BehaviorId in HoverMenuExtender  like this BehaviorID="HoverMenuBehavior"

Comment: Tried. But it is the same like before

Comment: Tried with all above solutions. But did not work for me

Comment: Refer this that you have used all properties http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HoverMenu/HoverMenu.aspx